# init.rc doesn't start my service on boot completed event

Tags: boot, shell, init.d, aosp

I've added the following snippet to the end of `/system/core/rootdir/init.rc` file.

```
on property:dev.bootcomplete=1
    start bootcomplete_handler

service bootcomplete_handler /system/bin/bc_handler.sh
    class main
    user root
    group root
    disabled
    oneshot
```

And `/system/bin/bc_handler.sh`:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
echo hi > /data/hi.txt
monkey -p com.example.package 1
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to run an app when device boots up. That `echo` is just for test, as I check existence of `/data/hi.txt`, it won't be created when device boots up. Could someone help me? BTW, I'm using bullhead if matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your service name is too long (or contains invalid characters).
>
> Service names can be at most 16 characters long, and can contain
>   alphanumeric characters, "_", and "-".
>
> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-4.2.2_r1.2/init/init_parser.c#411

<sub>attribution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33088141/1841194</sub>